# $_POST Variable Empty in Quercus Portlet on Liferay 6

Tags: liferay, quercus

My company is migrating from Luminis 5.1 to Luminis 5.3 (both built from Liferay 6), and we're running into a problem where portlets that POSTed fine in 5.1 no longer supply the Post Body in 5.3.

For example, this form

```
<form id="duplication-request" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>General Information</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name"
                       value="<?= $input->request->get('name', $name) ?>" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

would supply the `$_POST['name']` variable just fine in Luminis 5.1, but in 5.3, not even the 'name' index is registered.

If I serve it locally via `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080`, the `$_POST['name']` variable is registered correctly, leading me to think it's a problem with Quercus (which, unfortunately, isn't well supported)

Are there any settings in web.xml that I need to turn on in order to get Luminis to proxy the Request Body into Quercus so PHP can work with it?

Comment: I haven't ever used PHP based portlets, but an sceptical about this form - posting it to index.php looks like it's completely going to bypass Liferay, as the actual URL would be completely unknown at development time.

Comment: Try to set other value of attribute id and name except name like id ='abc' and name ='abc'

Comment: @OlafKock - yeah, I wish we didn't either. It's such a bubblegum-and-ducktape tactic. I've noticed that when I use index.php, liferay rewrites it to a longer url, something along the lines of "?p_p_id=blah&p_p_state=view&blah_WAR_blah_phpURI=index.php"

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH - what's posted is only a snippet of the code. There's more fields, written in the same format, such as email, division, total_pages, number_copies, etc. None of them show up when posted in Liferay.